# VS code после нажатия Enter переносит точку с запятой

Tags: visual-studio-code, курсор, перенос

При нажатии Enter, VS Code переносит точку с запятой на следующую строку. Как убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Жмите Tab вместо Enter

Answer (score 0):

Нужно нажать ctrl + enter - перенос строки вниз.  Ctrl+shift+enter - переносит строку вверх